# Django / Fetch : cannot access body after reading from request's data stream

Tags: json, django, rest, fetch

Im working with REST API and currently sending data from fetch to my django view. Im getting cannot access body after reading from request's data stream. what is wrong?

PS: i already tried using `request.data` but some other problems occuring

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt 
@api_view(['POST'])
def createNew(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = newsSerializer(data =data['title'])
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            # return Response(serializer.data)
            return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/news_list/')
```

my fetch method

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/news_create/'
            var title = document.getElementById('title').value

            fetch(url, {
                    method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        'title': title
                    }),
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log('Success:', data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                });

        });
```